# cascading context menu for highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is is possible to have a cascading context menu for highcharts ? I know there is options such as "save as jpg etc" but I want to build a little more complex one e.g.

```
"option 1"->"suboption 1"
            "suboption 2"
"option 2"->"suboption 1"
            "suboption 2"
```

So when the user hovers over option 1 then a little submenu pops up. Is it possible ?

Comment: Would you like to have this option inisde your chart, or you would like this context menu below/above your chart?

Comment: above the chart - in the right hand side corner like in the examples

Comment: Ine the Highcharts not, but you create that in HTML. Then catch the click event on element and call one of actions from Highcharts API, like exportChart. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.exportChart

Comment: Just to clarify what @SebastianBochan offered, while you can create some HTML elements within your Highcharts visualization, I would suggest you place your contextual menu **outside** the chart's code. While form elements like `<select>` will appear in `renderer.html`, you can't choose from the menu's options at runtime.